# Terraform Azure 2xLinux VM with httpd + LoadBalancer not working

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to create a Terraform PoC that has two centos VMs and an Azure Load Balancer. 
Each VM has one private and one public IP and installed the httpd package.
Even the elements are provisioned successful, accessing the Public IP of the Load Balancer does not return the default httpd content (inside the CentOS VM curl localhost or the IP returns the correct content).
No firewall enabled on CentOS. 
Below it the Terraform file. (Location i am using is westeurope).

**Q:** What am I missing in the configuration for the Load Balancer? All items are provisioned, no error from terraform, when accessing the public ip of the load balancer I get time out instead of the default apache page.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = var.rg_name
  location = var.location
    tags = {
    Owner       = var.tags["Owner"]
    Environment = var.tags["Environment"]
  }
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
 name                = var.vnet_name
 address_space       = ["192.168.0.0/16"]
 location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
 resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
    tags = {
    Owner       = var.tags["Owner"]
    Environment = var.tags["Environment"]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "test" {
 name                 = var.networks["subnet1"]
 resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
 virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test.name
 address_prefixes      = ["192.168.0.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "testlb" {
 name                         = "tf-demo-publicIPForLB"
 location                     = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
 resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
 sku                          = "Standard"
 allocation_method            = "Static"
 domain_name_label            = "acndemo"
    tags = {
    Owner       = var.tags["Owner"]
    Environment = var.tags["Environment"]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "test" {
 name                = "tf-demo-loadBalancer"
 location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
 resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
 sku                 = "Standard"
 frontend_ip_configuration {
   name                 = "tf-demo-lb-publicIPAddress"
   public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.testlb.id
 }
    tags = {
    Owner       = var.tags["Owner"]
    Environment = var.tags["Environment"]
  }
}


resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "test" {
 loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.test.id
 name                = "tf-demo-BackEndAddressPool"
}


resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "test" {
  count = 2
  network_interface_id    = "${azurerm_network_interface.test[count.index].id}"
  ip_configuration_name   = "tf-demo-nic-config${count.index}"
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.test.id
}

resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "test" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.test.id
  name                = "tf-demo-http-running-probe"
  protocol            = "Http"
  port                = 80
  request_path        = "/"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "test" {
  resource_group_name            = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.test.id
  name                           = "tf-demo-LBRule"
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = 80
  backend_port                   = 80
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "tf-demo-lb-publicIPAddress"
  backend_address_pool_id        = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.test.id
  probe_id                       = azurerm_lb_probe.test.id
}


resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {
 count                        = 2
 name                         = "tf-demo-publicIPForVM${count.index}"
 location                     = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
 resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
 sku                          = "Standard"
 allocation_method            = "Static"
 domain_name_label            = "acngrvm${count.index}"
 tags = {
    Owner       = var.tags["Owner"]
    Environment = var.tags["Environment"]
  }
}



resource "azurerm_network_interface" "test" {
 count               = 2
 name                = "tf-demo-nic${count.index}"
 location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
 resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name

 ip_configuration {
   name                          = "tf-demo-nic-config${count.index}"
   subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.test.id
   private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
   public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.test[count.index].id}"
 }
    tags = {
    Owner       = var.tags["Owner"]
    Environment = var.tags["Environment"]
  }
}


resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "test" {
    name                = "tf-demo-vm-nsg"
    location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name

    security_rule {
        name                       = "SSH"
        priority                   = 1001
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "22"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }
    tags = {
    Owner       = var.tags["Owner"]
    Environment = var.tags["Environment"]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "test" {
    count = length(azurerm_network_interface.test)
    network_interface_id      = "${azurerm_network_interface.test[count.index].id}"
    network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.test.id
}

resource "azurerm_availability_set" "test" {
 name                         = "tf-demo-availabilityset"
 location                     = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
 resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
 platform_fault_domain_count  = 2
 platform_update_domain_count = 2
 managed                      = true
    tags = {
    Owner       = var.tags["Owner"]
    Environment = var.tags["Environment"]
  }
}




resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "test" {
    count                   = 2
    name                    = "tfdemovm${count.index}"
    location                = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
    resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
    network_interface_ids   = [azurerm_network_interface.test[count.index].id]
    size                    = "Standard_DS1_v2"
    admin_username          = "centos"
    computer_name           = "tfdemovm${count.index}"
    availability_set_id     = azurerm_availability_set.test.id

        admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "centos"
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
        }

    os_disk {
        name                    = "tfdemovm${count.index}_OsDisk${count.index}"
        caching                 = "ReadWrite"
        storage_account_type    = "Standard_LRS"
    }

    source_image_reference {
        publisher = "OpenLogic"
        offer     = "CentOS"
        sku       = "7_8-gen2"
        version   = "latest"
   }
    tags = {
    Owner       = var.tags["Owner"]
    Environment = var.tags["Environment"]
  }

}
```

Comment: Don't you need port 80 also in your `destination_port_range` for the instance?

Comment: @Marcin Indeed. I had it wrong as i was waiting the NSG policy with ID 65001 from Any:Any AzureLoadBalancer:Any to allow the incoming traffic from Loadbalancer. you could provide me the answer to award you the correct answer thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by **not opening port 80** in `azurerm_network_security_group.test`. Only port 22 was allowed. Thus opening port 80 solved the issue.